# How to install oracle database on Mac OS

Tags: database, oracle, macos

I can install Oracle XE on windows, but I want it installed on Mac. Do you know how to install Oracle DB on mac and make queries on it using SQL Developer (which exists for Mac)?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle database is not supported natively on Mac. Even if you figured out a way to hack it, results would not be guaranteed. The only way to do it would be to use VirtualBox to create an Oracle Linux VM and install it on that, or download a pre-configured VM from Oracle as described here: https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-mac/

Note that the pre-configured VM uses Oracle Enterprise Edition, not Oracle XE. If you really want XE, you'd have to create a new VM and install on that.

Comment: Thanks. And, I am indifferent to the version. As long as it works, I am satisfied.